# HttpClient takes excessive amount of time (unless Http version is set to 1.0) when making multiple requests in parallel

Tags: c#, .net

After testing with the .net HttpClient I'm having the following issue. It will do the first 5-6 requests just fine (within 200ms or so), but after that it'll be a full 60 seconds before the rest complete - and they all complete nearly at once

Here is how I've been testing

```
        var tasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "secret_jwt");
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myapi/api/");

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(ProcessUrlAsync("organizations/id/185", client));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

-

```
    static private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessUrlAsync(string url, HttpClient client)
    {
        var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var message = await client.GetAsync(url);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
        return message;
    }
```

and my output is typically

174.5346
127.0873
141.9458
141.7396
153.6638
153.3449
61241.5598
61241.8476
61283.9076
61287.406
61326.0361
61328.7341
61368.6317
etc.

This is not the API I'm using that's the issue - I can point the HttpClient to any address and the same issue occurs

If I write my own GetAsync method that sets the Http version to 1.0...

```
    public new async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string url)
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
        {
            request.Version = HttpVersion.Version10; //removing this will reproduce the issue!

            return await SendAsync(request);
        }
    }
```

It works fine (all complete within a few hundred ms). Why is this, and what can I do to fix it whilst still using Http 1.1? I'm assuming it's something to do with 1.0 having connection : close and 1.1 having connection: keep-alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel rather silly, the solution is as simple as

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay getting back to you. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited to complete)

This looks like Socket exhaustion with `HttpClient`. There's lots of info available online if you search for that.

One solution is to only create one `HttpClient` and re-use that.
Another option is to add the header `Connection: close` to your request

This would explain why switching to HTTP/1.0 seemed to solve the issue -- as leaving connections open was added in 1.1.

As a side note to anyone who comes across this, you can't send the same `HttpRequestMessage` twice. You will need to create a new one for the second request.

Comment: I'm not sending the same message twice, if you're referring to `ReauthAndResendAsync` that creates a new request using the properties/headers/content of the original.

The server side is fine, postman completes requests in the tens of ms

Comment: Already reusing the same HttpClient. as per the code I showed. Also unsure how just 6 requests are causing socket exhaustion that causes it to hang for a full 60s?